# scrapy-splash script not finding CSS selector

Tags: scrapy, splash-screen, scrapy-splash

I'm trying to make a scrapy-splash script to get links for food items from:

https://www.realcanadiansuperstore.ca/Food/Meat-%26-Seafood/c/RCSS001004000000

When you visit it for the first time, it will make you select a region. I think I've correctly taken care of this by setting the cookies dict in my code below. I'm trying to get the links for all the food items in the carousel. I'm using splash because the carousel is made by javascript and a regular request and parsing with beautiful soup wouldn't show it in the html. My problem is that I'm not getting any data into my 'items' dict.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'quotes'
    start_urls = ["https://www.realcanadiansuperstore.ca/Food/Meat-%26-
    Seafood/c/RCSS001004000000"]


    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield SplashRequest(url, cookies={'currentRegion' :'CA-BC'}, 
            callback = self.parse, endpoint = 'render.html', args = {'wait':0.5},
                            )

def parse(self, response):

    item = {}
    item['urls'] = []

    itemList = response.css('div.product-name-wrapper > a > ::attr(href)').extract()

    for links in itemList:
        item['urls'].append(links)

    yield item
```

I'm thinking that my cookies aren't set properly so it's taking me to the page where I need to select a region.

By the way, I've got splash running on a docker console as well. If I go to my localhost in a browser, it shows the splash page.

Here's the output I get from crawling the spider:

```
<GET https://www.realcanadiansuperstore.ca/Food/Meat-%26-
Seafood/c/RCSS001004000000 via http://localhost:8050/render.html> 
(referer: None)
2017-07-04 16:44:05 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 
https://www.realcanadiansuperstore.ca/Food/Meat-%26-
Seafood/c/RCSS001004000000>
{'urls': []}
```

What could be going wrong here? I've got my settings file filled out as described here:  https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash

Ok I've been able to get the localhost browser instance of Splash to render the HTML I need by setting the cookies like so:

```
function main(splash)
    splash:add_cookie{"sessionid", "237465ghgfsd", "/", 
    domain="http://example.com"}
    splash:go("http://example.com/")
    return splash:html()
end
```

But this is in the browser as a script you can enter. How do I apply this to my python script? Is there a different way to add a cookie in Python?

Answer (score 0):

If there is a script which works for you, you can use /execute endpoint to execute this script:

```
yield SplashRequest(url, endpoint='execute', args={'lua_source': my_script})
```

scrapy-splash also allows to set up transparent cookie handling, so that cookies persist across SplashRequests, just like in regular scrapy.Requests:

```
script = """
function main(splash)
  splash:init_cookies(splash.args.cookies)
  assert(splash:go{
    splash.args.url,
    headers=splash.args.headers,
    http_method=splash.args.http_method,
    body=splash.args.body,
    })
  assert(splash:wait(0.5))

  local entries = splash:history()
  local last_response = entries[#entries].response
  return {
    url = splash:url(),
    headers = last_response.headers,
    http_status = last_response.status,
    cookies = splash:get_cookies(),
    html = splash:html(),
  }
end
"""

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):

    # def my_parse...
    #   ...
        yield SplashRequest(url, self.parse_result,
            endpoint='execute',
            cache_args=['lua_source'],
            args={'lua_source': script},
        )

    def parse_result(self, response):
        # here response.body contains result HTML;
        # response.headers are filled with headers from last
        # web page loaded to Splash;
        # cookies from all responses and from JavaScript are collected
        # and put into Set-Cookie response header, so that Scrapy
        # can remember them.
```

See [examples](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash#examples) in scrapy-splash README.